# SASS syntax highlighting, code completion, and automatic compling in Eclipse/Aptana

Tags: css, eclipse, sass, aptana

Just as the title says, how can I accomplish these things. I am using an OpenSUSE distro.

Please note, I have already been through the numerous related posts on this topic. I have tried all the suggestions and they have not worked out for me for one reason or another. I will be happy to describe the undesired results those answers gave me if you can help me see what I did wrong. (Just trying to avoid the 'duplicate question' with a link and then a down vote passer-bys...)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a plugin to automatically transpile SASS files (amongst others) automatically, which you can use for the compiling part.

-> https://github.com/gossi/eclipse-transpiler-plugin